# Finding variables in code

Tags: code-golf, string

Given some code in your language as a string, find and display all the variable names.

Examples in pseudocode:

```
a=2
b=3
for(i, 0->9) do b=b-10
if a=b then write "a equals b"
```

Returns: `a b i`

```
abcdefgh=20000000000000
bcdifhgs="hello"
if abcdefgh=bcdifhgs then da44="hax"
if abcdefgh*2=da44 then write da44
```

Returns: `abcdefgh bcdifhgs da44`

```
2=3
3=5
5=7
if 2=7 then exit
```

Returns:

```
a=2
while True do b=3
```

Returns: `a b`

Shortest code wins.

For stack-based languages, display the highest height of the stack.
For memory cell based languages, display all the memory cells that have been changed.

Comment: How is the code given, as a string input to our program, or are we to append our code to the 'input' program?

Comment: I was soo excited to answer with an empty brainfuck program until I read the last line.

Comment: Someone should solve this without using regular expressions :)

Comment: Could you please explain the last two lines in your question or show an example?

Comment: @MikeDtrick: Stack-based: `push 2 items pull 1 item push 2 items pull 3 items` will return 3. Memory-cell: think Brainfuck, and all cell values which have been changed by `+` or `-`.

Comment: More interesting, in case of `while false { b = 3 }` should it return `b`? Please clarify.

Comment: @ArtemIce: Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Python 3, <s>73</s> <s>66</s> 86

Now follows the updated test cases:

```
import sys
print(*set(compile(sys.argv[1],'','exec').co_names)-set(dir(__builtins__)))
```

Note that this also prints the names of non-builtin objects and methods / attributes of objects (e.g. if you use `sys.argv` in the input code it'll print `sys` and `argv`). Still, it does technically fit the test cases.

Assuming we're allowed to simply run the code, it can be done in 66 characters. Note that this fails the `while True` test case and, unlike the above solution, does not print things like `sys` and `argv`:

```
import sys
print(*(lambda:(exec(sys.argv[1]),set(locals())))()[1])
```

Comment: Only problem is, you have to actually run the code to get the variables.

Comment: I have put in another test case, please modify your answer to fit it.

Comment: Alright, I've changed my answer.

Comment: Very interesting... I've never heard of a `code` object or the `compile` built-in before.

Comment: This is really the only answer which runs correctly for the last test case, so answer to you!

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 2

```
[]
```

Only if you take the word "variable" literally.

Comment: For all those not knowing Haskell: It actually doesn't have any variables; anything is constant.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

Kind of cheating, I guess... If `code` contains Ruby code, then:

```
pre = global_variables
eval code
(global_variables - pre + local_variables + self.instance_variables - [:code, :pre]).each do |x|
  puts x.to_s
end
```

Example:
`code = "a = 3; @b = 5; $c = 6, @@d = 10"`

Output:

```
$c
@b
```

*Works only with global and instance vars so far.*

## zsh

```
set > /tmp/set.1
eval $code
set > /tmp/set.2
diff -a /tmp/set.1 /tmp/set.2 | grep -vE "HISTCMD|LINENO|RANDOM|SECONDS|pipestatus" | grep -E ">[^=]+"
```

Example:

$code = `'zzz=3; xxx="hello"'`

Output

```
> xxx=hello
> zzz=3
```

## Clojure, 53

```
(pr(map #(last %)(re-seq #"\( *def +([a-z-])+"code))
```

Example:

```
user=> (def code "(def a 1) (     def    b     ( +  3 5 )))")
#'user/code
user=> (pr(map #(last %)(re-seq #"\( *def +([a-z-]+)"code)))
("a" "b")nil
user=>
```

Comment: I have put in another test case, please modify your answer to fit it.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 104

```
import sys,re,keyword
print(set(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b",sys.argv[1]))-set(keyword.kwlist+dir(__builtins__)))
```

Comment: This also prints integers and words inside of strings...

Comment: @Fraxtil: Yes, I realized this the other day :/ Still trying to think of a way to handle string literals without adding to much to the character count.

Answer (score 1):

## HQ9+ (or H9+), 0

Is cheating allowed? In this case, the solution is a program of zero length, because the language has no variables, and has no memory cells, stack or any other form of storage. So it outputs nothing.

<sub>First I wanted to write Brainf*ck, but then I realized the "memory cell" rule.</sub>

Comment: Actually, you have a memory cell. (Remember that nice operator called `+` [increment the counter]? It's pretty pointless since you can't read out the counter at all, but the counter is definitly a variable. )

Comment: I always assumed it is the `program counter`. If you require to also print the PC, it would invalidate all other answers, because none of them print it :)

Comment: This is code golf. Cheating is encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Python, 111

I am pretty new to code golf.. tips are appreciated, but here is an alternative approach

```
import ast as a
s=set()
v=a.NodeVisitor
v.visit_Name=lambda t,n:s.add(n.id)
v().visit(a.parse(input()))
print s
```

Answer (score -1):

## MATLAB, 12

```
eval('<PROGRAM STRING HERE>');who
```

Comment: I have put in another test case, please modify your answer to fit it.

Comment: @beary605 no need to change anything :)

Comment: Even better for you. ;D

Comment: I'm fairly certain, although can't test it, that if the <PROGRAM STRING HERE> is a piece of code that never terminates that your program will never print the variables.